# The practical importance of Graph Isomorphism Problem

Tags: graphs, graph-isomorphism, applications

It is known that Graph Isomorphism is important in chemistry (studying molecule structures) and in chip design. Are there other applications of significant practical importance, and how much money is involved?

Is the industry interested in new efficient algorithms, or WL and DeepWalk are enough? Having a new efficient algorithm for testing graph isomorphism, is it worth patenting it?

Comment: (There are stackexchange.com sites for [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

Comment: Isomorphism of *pieces* of graphs is also used in procedural generation (eg. of video game content) via generative graph grammars.